# how to axios post to SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

```
var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('c2Dashboard Data')/items";

var digest = document.querySelector('#__REQUESTDIGEST').value;
console.log(digest);
var axiosConfig =  {
                  headers: {  
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",                     
                        "X-RequestDigest": digest
                  }
               }

var postData = { 
              Permanent: '0', 
              Itinerant: '0', 
              Region: 'Western', 
              Service: 'Army' 
           }

axios.post(endPointUrl, postData, axiosConfig)
               .then(function(response){
                        console.log('saved successfully')
                    })
               .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
```

I get the following error about 'val' but there is no 'val' just 'value'

**'Promise' is undefined
File: axios.min.js, Line: 8, Column: 401**

Comment: the problem isn't with your code, it's with your setup.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: where does this code live? How's it deployed? How are you referencing your dependencies?

Comment: The code is in SharePoint and used in a content editor webpart.  The dependencies are referenced in an html file where my js file withe the axios code is referenced also.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code to POST your data in SharePoint list:

```
$.ajax({  
     async: true, 
     url: endPointUrl,  
     method: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify({  
         '__metadata': {  
             'type': 'SP.Data.ListItem' // it defines the ListEntityTypeName  
         },
         Permanent: '0', 
         Itinerant: '0', 
         Region: 'Western', 
         Service: 'Army' 
     }),  
     headers: {  
         "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
         "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
     },  
     success: function(data) {  
         console.log("Item created successfully"); 
     },  
     error: function(error) {  
         console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
  
     }        
})
```

Before using this function pass the `ListEntityTypeName` of your own list in `__metadata` property.

You can get this property by hitting below URL in browser tab:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(listName)/entityTypeName
```

**OR**

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(listName)?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

**Sources**:

1. [SP.List.entityTypeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245672.aspx).
2. [CRUD Operations In SharePoint REST API Using jQuery AJAX](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-api-using-jquery-ajax/).

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to update list items

```
var getData =({});
var data = {
    Title: "1",
    FieldName1: "FieldName1 Value",
    FieldName2: "FieldName2 Value",
    FieldName3: "FieldName3 Value",
}
for(var d in data){
    getData[d] = getData[d];  
}
getData.__metadata ={
    type:  "SP.Data.MylistTitleListItem"
}
console.log('getData');
console.log(getData);   
var digest = document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value;   
//We get list item by Id 19:
var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MylistTitle')/items(19)";
var axiosConfig =  {
    headers:{
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "X-RequestDigest": digest,
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"                
    }                     
}   
axios.post(endPointUrl, getData, axiosConfig)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Response');
        console.log(response);                   
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245803/how-to-axios-post-to-sharepoint-2013-list
        console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKED FOR ME: Saving only.

```
var digest = document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value;
    var query = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('mylist title')/items";       
    var axiosConfig =  {
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": digest,
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }

    axios.post(query, _this.Model, axiosConfig)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log('Savede Data');
            console.log(response.data);                   
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245803/how-to-axios-post-to-sharepoint-2013-list
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: what is ```_this.Model```?  Where did it come from?