# How to Create item in SharePoint Online using REST api? If list name contains underscore(_)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, error

I am easily able to create record in other lists using rest API.

But with this one list, api failed.
**Listname**: Project_List
Can anyone please help me.

Thanks

**Code**:

```
 function GetItemTypeForListName(name){
        return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";  
    }
function AddListItem(){
var listName = "Project_List";  
var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
            var myID ="";   
            var name = "276 Flinders St";
              
            var item = {  
                "__metadata": { "type": itemType },  
                "Title": name
            };
            $.ajax({  
                url:  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl  + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + myID + ")",  
                type: "POST", 
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                data: JSON.stringify(item),  
                headers: {  
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
                    "IF-MATCH": "*",  
                    "X-HTTP-Method":"POST",  
                },  
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");  
                },  
                error: function (data) {  
                    alert("failed");  
                }  
            });  
        }
```

**Edit 1:**
I tried with all solution which you guys gave, but still not working

Error screenshot attached:
[image]

**Edit 2:**

ListItemtype:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the error you got to your question?

Comment: added error in question,

Comment: Please add a error message. To see error message use your code like: `error: function (error) {   console.log(error);   }` and add the error message you got in console. Also, try the suggestions given below in my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you are getting this issue because you are passing wrong `type` inside `__metadata`.

Before using the main REST call check the `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` of your own list and pass it in `__metadata` property.

You can get this property by hitting below URL in browser tab:

```
https://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

Do not use the `GetItemTypeForListName` function in your code. This is kind of a hack which will work correctly only if there are no spaces or special characters in your list name.

Hit above URL in browser tab and pass the `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` you got from this endpoint in your `itemType` variable.

Check my answer given in below question:

[how to axios post to SharePoint 2013 list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245803/how-to-axios-post-to-sharepoint-2013-list)

**Note**:

Generally, `_` in list name gets converted into `_x005f_` and space in list name gets converted into `_x0020_` in `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` of SharePoint list. But, it is always recommended to use above REST endpoint and check the `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` of your list.

Comment: thanks for replying. i tried with all these not unfortunately not working

Comment: Still getting same error:
responseText: "{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A type named 'HotWorkPermit3_x005f_ImagesListItem' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type."}}}"

Comment: Try running this in new browser tab: `<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/cactus/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HotWorkPermit3_Images')/entityTypeName` and attach the screenshot of the result to your question. You need to use the result you get from this endpoint.

Comment: added, see if it can help me

Comment: This is strange, it should have worked for you. can you please try again calling this endpoint: `<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/cactus/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HotWorkPermit3_Images')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName` and check if it is returning the same result or different.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add "SP.Data" before `entityTypeName` in metadata. that is why it is causing this issue. Check updated answer and if it helped you to solve your issue please [upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

Is this display name of the list?

Try with `%5F`  var `listName = "Project%5FList";`

OR

```
/lists/getbytitle('" + encodeURIComponent(listName) + "')
```

https://julieturner.net/2016/09/special-characters-in-rest-listitem-metadata/

Answer (score 1):

While you are generating the type using : GetItemTypeForListName in you machine, You should not use like this pattern. You can get the type from the rest end point. The list name with special character like _ will not have the type with proper pattern. Check the type of this list.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all guys who helped me to solve my issue.

I solved issue by removing quotes from item and previously i was using a variable to store column data and name but now i am directly writing inside ajax.

That's now working successfully, don't know why its not working when i use variable.
For further clarification, i added screenshot also.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the problem is that SharePoint will escape special characters, causing '_ ' to ' *x005f* '.The title will not affect the excution,but the itemType get by the function `GetItemTypeForListName` is wrong.

**My test code works well:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function (){
CreateListItemWithDetails("test")
})
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName) {
   
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.Test_x005f_testListItem" },
        "Title": "test"
    };

 

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('test_test')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("s");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

You could update the GetItemTypeForListName,when the itemtype get by GetItemTypeForListName contains '_',we should replace it with ' *x005f* '.